# Laravel multiple occurrences of relation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an api for a clothing store with Laravel 5.4 and I have this situation. I have a Rack that has clothes on it. But the same piece can occur multiple times on the rack.

```
rack
-id
-description
product
-id
-description
product_rack
-id
-rack_id
-product_id
```

I have a many to many relation because a product can occur on many racks and a rack has multiple products. However I'am not sure how I can attach a product multiple times to a rack.

Like for instance Rack with id of 1 has 2 times product 5 and 1 time product 3.

I can use the `attach()` function but if I `detach()` it releases all products from the rack instead of one.

Comment: Look at Laravel's many to many relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: hmm..You want the same product appear multiple times on the same rack? What's the purpose of that...

Comment: Well if you go to a store there is a high change that a piece of clothing occurs multiple times on a rack. I want my api to be able to display that.

Comment: Well if you want to do that, the logic should probably be in the view logic. I still don't understand why not just have a count displayed next to the product? Is each clothes has very low number counts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column to the product_rack table describing the number of products in the specific rack

example :

rack_id  | product_id | count

1        | 5          | 2
1        | 3          | 1

You can retrieve the count using from product end

```
$product->rack->pivot->count
```

and from rack end

```
$rack->product->pivot->count
```

Read retrieving intermediate table columns in the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and how would I update the count column?

Comment: I think when you add or take out items.